# 500 error mystery happens on server only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

I have zero issues locally getting back the requested data from a .net MVC application, but on the server the ajax jquery call reports a 500 error.  Typically I can step through the code locally and figure out what "could" be causing the 500 error on the server.

This time I am realizing that I really need a better coding strategy to trap errors and either log them or report them back to me

```
public ActionResult PhotoList(int tblGateCode_ID)
{
    try
    {
        context = new DBGate();
        var images = context.tblGateCodeImages.Where(x => x.tblGateCode_ID == tblGateCode_ID);
        foreach (var img in images)
        {
            img.GatePhoto = null;
        }
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel
        {
            GateCodeImageList = images.ToList()
        };
        return Json(viewModel, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        //??
        }
   }
}
```

**Update:**

I did try adding in code into my catch

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    return Json(e.Message, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Either I'm not allowed to do that... or some other reason I still get the 500?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: You can use you browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response and see more details of the error

Comment: The response is just not good enough,  what I want to do is just pass back the Exception.   So i suppose   e.Message

Comment: How much access do you have to the server? If you can view eventlogs, you could write the exception.message to an eventlog to help debug. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307024

Comment: I do happen to have access to this server  - It would be super nice to just have the exception message be passed back to the caller  - for me to use with console.log

Comment: What is really odd that even when I alter the json return to only pass back a empty viewmodel, that I still get a 500 error.  It is like the try /catch is not even really working IMO

Comment: Is it getting to the catch part? As @TheShaman suggested, you could use eventlogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple causes for this, anything from missing dependencies to incorrect server set-up. I would hence recommend setting up some proper error logging, you will soon see from these logs what the error is.

The easier way to do this in ASP.net is to install Elmah. Do this via nuget.

Additional point to note here, is that by default in web api you will not pick up all errors as [described here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling). In order to make sure you catch all exceptions add the below code and register it at startup in the WebAppConfig class in the method register by adding config.Filters.Add(new RestfulModelStateFilterAttribute());

An alternative to the below is to add the nuget package Elmah.Contrib.WebApi

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Elmah;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

/// <summary>
/// see http://sergeyakopov.com/2015/03/restful-validation-with-aspnet-web-api-and-fluentvalidation
/// and https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi/blob/master/src/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute.cs
/// this is a combination of both, but with logging enabled for anything above 400, not 500 like the link above.
/// </summary>
public class RestfulModelStateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        var e = actionExecutedContext.Exception;
        if (e != null)
        {
            RaiseOrLog(e, actionExecutedContext);
        }
        else if ((int)actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode >= 400)
        {
            RaiseOrLog(
                new HttpException(
                    (int)actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode,
                    ResolveMessage(actionExecutedContext)),
                actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }

    private string ResolveMessage(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        const string messageKey = "Message";

        var defaultMessage = actionExecutedContext.Response.ReasonPhrase;
        var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent<HttpError>;
        if (objectContent == null) return defaultMessage;

        var value = objectContent.Value as HttpError;
        if (value == null) return defaultMessage;

        if (!value.ContainsKey(messageKey)) return defaultMessage;

        var message = value[messageKey] as string;
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) ? defaultMessage : message;
    }

    private void RaiseOrLog(Exception exception, HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (RaiseErrorSignal(exception) // prefer signaling, if possible
            || IsFiltered(actionExecutedContext)) // filtered?
            return;

        LogException(exception);
    }

    private static bool RaiseErrorSignal(Exception e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
            return false;
        var application = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
        if (application == null)
            return false;
        var signal = ErrorSignal.Get(application);
        if (signal == null)
            return false;
        signal.Raise(e, context);
        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsFiltered(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var config = HttpContext.Current.GetSection("elmah/errorFilter")
                     as ErrorFilterConfiguration;

        if (config == null)
            return false;

        var testContext = new ErrorFilterModule.AssertionHelperContext(
                                  context.Exception, HttpContext.Current);

        return config.Assertion.Test(testContext);
    }

    private static void LogException(Exception e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(context).Log(new Error(e, context));
    }
}
```